# GTM - Track all downloads except certain classes

Tags: triggers, google-tag-manager

I currently have a trigger in GTM that tracks when certain documents are downloaded, such as pdfs, xlsx, png, docx, jpg... etc..

This is setup to track on the entire site, however I have a specific section that I don't want tracked by this catch all.

I've been trying to add an exception that says if a download link contains the class "Library_Download" then don't track it under the catch all trigger.

I'm trying to bring more clarity to what types of files are being downloaded.

I have tried adding exceptions to the tag, or adding validation to the trigger that and I seem to be missing something.

Catch All Trigger

```
Trigger Type: Click - Just Links
Trigger Fires On: Element URL Path - matches RegEx
\.(pdf|xlsx|png|docx|jpg|jpeg|zip|pat|dwg)$
```

How do I not count any link that contains the class "Library_Download" Or is there another way I should have them omitted?

I've created the following trigger and added it as an exception to the tag but it didn't work.

```
Trigger Type: Custom Event
Event name: \* (Enabled regex matching)
Trigger Fires on: Click Class - contains - "Library_booking"
```

**Nov 21 Edit**

So to clarify a bit more with HTML. Below is what I'm currently using for my library_download link. I'm currently only concerned with the pdfdownload.pdf

```
<div class="resource_row">          
<div class="resource_item large <?php echo $post->post_name; ?>" data-filter-item data-filter-name="<?php echo $post->post_name; ?>">
        <a href="www.librarywebsite.com/librarypage/" ><?php the_post_thumbnail('medium'); ?></a>
        <p><?php the_title(); ?></p>
        <ul class="resource_icons">
          <li><a href="www.librarywebsite.com/librarypage/" target="_blank"><img src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/img/icon-download.png" alt="Download PDF" /></a></li>
          <li><a href="www.librarywebsite.com/pdfdownload.pdf" target="www.librarywebsite.com/pdfdownload.pdf" class="Library_Download"><img src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/img/icon-library.png" alt="library" /></a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
</div>
```

This is how a regular link would look like (the only thing that's changed is I have removed the class Library_Download

```
<div class="resource_row">
      <div class="resource_item large <?php echo $post->post_name; ?>" data-filter-item data-filter-name="<?php echo $post->post_name; ?>">
        <a href="www.librarywebsite.com/librarypage/" ><?php the_post_thumbnail('medium'); ?></a>
        <p><?php the_title(); ?></p>
        <ul class="resource_icons">
          <li><a href="www.librarywebsite.com/librarypage/" target="_blank"><img src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/img/icon-download.png" alt="Download PDF" /></a></li>
          <li><a href="www.librarywebsite.com/pdfdownload.pdf" target="www.librarywebsite.com/pdfdownload.pdf" class="non-Librarylink"><img src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/img/icon-library.png" alt="library" /></a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
  </div>
```

Like I've mentioned my catch all trigger currently get's triggered on every single PDF download, I just want to omit the links that have class "Library_download".

Comment: Could you please share a relevant example of the links, you would like to track? E.g. the html code of the anchor tag, and its child elements.

Comment: K, see my edits above from Nov 21, let me know if you need more clarification.

Comment: If you check the Link Click event in GTM debug mode, what do you see for the trigger conditions of this specific tag? What are the relevant variable values?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you made a mistake in your regex in "Custom Event" exclusion rule (that's why this rule doesn't work). You have "\*" (with regex matching checked). Try to change regex to:

```
.*
```

This will match every event (and then of course preserve this: Trigger Fires on: Click Class - contains - "Library_booking").

In your case regex like this: "\*" will match only to event strictly named as "*" (star)

Comment: So I did try this and it is still not working for me, could it be that the trigger element url path is more powerful than trying to select a class? Or do you have any other things I could try/do you need more info on anything?